# Are the module paramters set by a kernel module with "module_param" possible to read from a seperate module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am currently working on a kernel module where I wish to read a kernel parameter of a different kernel module. Stored in `/sys/module/MODULE_NAME/parameters`.

Specifically I want to read the **alpha** value of **tcp_vegas** which is set as follows:

```
/* From net/ipv4/tcp_vegas.c */
static int alpha = 2;
/* ... */
module_param(alpha, int, 0644);`
```

Is there a good, clean way of reading this value from within my kernel module using a kernel API?

Comment: Yes, they are for sure. You can read `/sys/module/<YOUR-MODULE>/parameters/`. Are you asking whether there's a kernel API for that?

Comment: Yes, I am asking if there is a kernel API for that. Sorry, was a bit unclear about that.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a good, clean way, but there is `filp_open`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, if module has customized `->read()` for module parameter you may not get the result. I guess the proper way is to iterrate over all linked modules and check the special linker section, etc (yes, I mean linked by the kernel linker at run-time).